# BS4 and onclick(): how to make action?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

In order to get info user have to click this link:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="startScorebot();">here</a>
```

How to get it pressed by `bs4`? Or maybe there is other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use selenium to perform clicks. Mechanize might be useful too.